# Why hashcode is called in this example?

Tags: java, hashcode

Can someone please explain why [hashCode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) is called in the example below?

```
import java.util.List;

public class JSSTest extends Object{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        JSSTest a = new JSSTest();
        JSSTest b = new JSSTest();
        List<JSSTest> list = new java.util.ArrayList<JSSTest>();
        list.add(a);
        list.add(b);
        System.out.println(list.get(0));
        System.out.println(list.get(1));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        System.out.println("equals");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        System.out.println("hashCode");
        return super.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Outcome:

```
hashCode 0
JSSTest@1bab50a
hashCode 0
JSSTest@c3c749
```

Comment: Have you tried taking a stack trace or adding a breakpoint at line in a debugger?

Comment: It would be a huge clue to look at the number `1bab50a` or `c3c749` and see how it compares to the object's hashcode.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default `toString()` implementation calls `hashCode`. This has nothing to do with lists.

Here's a fairly minimal repro:

```
public class JSSTest {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        JSSTest test = new JSSTest();
        // Just to show it's not part of creation...
        System.out.println("After object creation");
        test.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        System.out.println("equals");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        System.out.println("hashCode");
        return super.hashCode();
    }
}
```

(You could override `toString()` to display before / super call / after details, too.)

It's documented in `Object.toString()`:

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

Answer (score 7):

```
System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

I believe it's part of the Object.toString() method that all objects have unless you override toString() in your own class. Try that and see.

Comment: Thx. Thats correct too but can only mark one correct answer. Given u tickup :)

Answer (score 6):

because the `toString()` implementation in `Object` calls it..

```
 public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }
```

Overwrite `toString`, and it won't be called

Comment: Thx. Thats correct too but can only mark one correct answer. Given u tickup :)